# Android. Sharing image error

Tags: android, share

I write the app that process image somehow and than I want to share it. Meaning to allow user to share it using standard share activity. When I do this I get error messages. When I choose Gmail it writes `Can't open empty file`. But the file is saved, I can open it with the Gallery or any other app. So I can not figure out what I do wrong.

Here is my sharing code:

```
public static void shareImage(Bitmap bmp, Context context) {

    String pathBitmap = saveBitmap(bmp, context);
    if (pathBitmap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.save_photo_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(pathBitmap);
    if (bitmapUri != null) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/png");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
    }
}
```

Here is how I save the bitmap:

```
public static String saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp, Context context) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_SSS");
    String fileName   = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    File fNew = new File(MyApp.getInstance().getPhotosPath(), fileName + ".png");

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(fNew);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
        // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.photos_saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return fNew.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here are functions that returns the path. `createFolder()` is called from apps `onCreate()`

```
private void createFolder() {

    _pathPhotos = "";
    try {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WonderApp");
        folder.mkdir();
        _pathPhotos = folder.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getPhotosPath() {
    return _pathPhotos;
}
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: The error just happen with gmail? Try with apps that you already have given the permission to access your directory. Maybe gmail just can't read it and is given you a bad error message.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work with google drive either

Comment: What `MyApp.getInstance().getPhotosPath()` returns? Could you paste the function implementation?

Comment: Please find it in original post. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the problem. The problem actually was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318692/android-attaching-a-file-to-gmail-cant-attach-empty-file). As [GuiFGDeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4528698/guifgdeo) kindly wrote, the problem is URI that should be content URI instead of file URI. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) you can find how Google propose to solve the problem. I found a bit shorter way.

When you insert image into media store you receive exactly what you need - content URI. And voilà!

```
public static void shareImage(Bitmap bmp, Context context) {

    String sImageUrl = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bmp, "title" , "description");
    Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(sImageUrl);

    if (savedImageURI != null) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, savedImageURI);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
    }

}
```